# Advanced Java idiom for 2+ classes implementing a generic interface

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, meta, typesafe

I came across the following situation and am wondering whether the way I implemented it is good in terms of reusability and speed, I'd also be interested to have an actual compilable solution since the one below doesn't compile (I hope some one finds the culprit and has a simple and elegant idea on this).

There are two Java classes "Vec3F" and "Vec3" that implement basic vector math for floating point and double types. Both implement interface below as follows:

```
public final class Vec3 implements Vec<Vec3> {
//..
    public double distance(Vec3 other) { /*..*/ }
}

public interface Vec<V> {

    double distance(V other);   
}
```

I did this to be able to have some algorithms work with both types of vector implementations, and here comes the problem:

```
public class Toolbox {

public static <T> double getAllDistances(List<Vec<T>> points) {
    Vec<T> prevPoint = points.get(0);
    Vec<T> point;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int len = points.size();
    for (int i=1;i<len; i++) {
        point = points.get(i);
        //-> this doesn't compile: 
        //The method distance(T) in the type Vec<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Vec<T>)    
        sum+=point.distance(prevPoint);
        prevPoint = point;
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

I know that I could implement 'getAllDistances' twice but this is what I want to avoid. I'd love to have a Toolbox class that can do some meta-algorithms based on methods declared in the interface.
I also want to avoid to change the method implementation of e.g. distance(Vec3 other) to have the interface passed (because it uses e.g. other.x*other.x directly to avoid calling any getters).

I'd be glad for some thoughts on this and hope the question is clear and specific enough, thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this a job for the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: You need to clarify what the types stand for. Is a "point" really a vector of T, or a T object? What is the relationship between Vec and Vec3? Is "other" in distance(V other) a point? Where is Vec3F?

Comment: Vec3F is implementing the same interface as Vec3 but uses float x,y,z; instead of double x,y,z; in all of its methods. Other is of type "Vec3" when implemented in Vec3 and of type "Vec3F" when distance is implemented for the floating point Vec3F class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably wanted to define the Vec interface as:

```
public interface Vec<V extends Vec<V>>
```

This can be difficult to look at, as it seems at first glance like an illegal forward reference, but it is perfectly valid and normal (and in fact is used in [java.lang.Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)).

Whenever you have a `Vec<T>` instance, you must pass a `T`, not a `Vec<T>`, to the `distance` method.  So you would need to define your getAllDistances method like this:

```
public static <T extends Vec<T>> double getAllDistances(List<T> points) {
    T prevPoint = points.get(0);
    T point;
```

Comment: The interface definition is indeed a little difficult to look at. However it also works without this definition. What exactly is it used for?

Comment: It restricts V to only implementations of Vec.  It seemed like the logical thing to do, but as you said, it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Indeed V's bound is not required in this case. This is similar to `Collections.sort(List)`. all that's needed is that the element type can compareTo/calcDistanceTo the same type.

Comment: It's beautiful, yet somehow hard to get the bound thing right, most of the time I happen to encapsulate them too often, thanks!

Comment: If I add the Vec < V extends Vec < V > > to the definition of the interface, it's always required to use the < T extends Vec < T > > in the methods if a Vec < T > is in the parameter. I still don't really get the proper use, or merely a 'benefit' of using it.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a typesafe way:

```
public static <T extends Vec<T>> double getAllDistances(List<T> points) {
    T prevPoint = points.get(0);
    T point;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int len = points.size();
    for (int i=1;i<len; i++) {
        point = points.get(i);

        sum+=point.distance(prevPoint);
        prevPoint = point;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This solves the compiler issue by moving away from List < Vec < T> > in the parameter and defining it as the bounds of T.
Besides the lengthy method declaration it looks quite simple and intuitive to me.

Comment: Also, don't hesitate with the ugly solution that casts between `T` and `Vec<T>`. You know they are the same thing, so it's safe.